# Redirecting a CSS file based on .htaccess rules

Tags: apache2, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to hack the CSS files on OSTicket by replacing them with my own custom ones when a specific URL is accessed.

The URL that is accessed for this example is:
`http://example.com/helpdesk/scp/css/main.css`

and I would like it to use the CSS file at:
`http://example.com/test.css`

Why won't this .htaccess file (in web root, not `/helpdesk/scp/`) work? Is there an easy way to debug these rules, some way to find out what Apache did when the URL was accessed and where it's failing? `error.log` doesn't show anything useful.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)main\.css$ /test.css [NC, L]
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete space between `NC,` and `L`. Also check `AllowOverride All` (or `FileInfo`):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)main\.css$ /test.css [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you! Turned out that I not only had AllowOverride to None (I didn't write the config, but should have checked it) and once that was fixed I realized mod_rewrite wasn't even loaded.

Answer (score 1):

See the documentation on [RewriteLog](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) and [RewriteLogLevel](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteloglevel) for how to debug rewrite rules.